# How can I create a standard Blu-Ray video (not data) disc from multiple MKVs?

Tags: burning, blu-ray, matroska

I have multiple video files in the [MKV format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matroska). I want to turn these into a Blu-Ray disc that would play on a PS3 or PC with PowerDVD. The easier the better; I don't want to mess with bitrate and complicated settings each time if possible.

More details if it helps:

- I create the MKV files with [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr) usually.
- Simple menu on the Blu-Ray would be nice.
- My burner is a Lite-On IHBS112-29 BD+R.

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear, but I do not want to burn a data disc with MKV files. I want to burn a true blu-ray compatible disc that can be played by any blu-ray player.

Comment: I edited the question to make it sound less like a shopping/product request.

Answer (score 4):

First use [tsMuxerR](http://www.videohelp.com/tools/tsMuxeR) to convert to BD then use ImgBurn.

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) will burn BD, but will not create a menu - but on the other hand, it is open source.

And here is a [link](http://www.bitburners.com/articles/convert-mkv-files-to-blu-ray-or-avchd-for-playstation-3-using-tsmuxer/4019/) to a short guide how to do it. Enjoy the quality.

Comment: If I use the "Build" mode directly in imgBurn, it will just burn the MKV directly to the disc, and that would require a Blu-Ray player capable of playing MKV, correct? I was looking for a solution that would convert it to blu-ray(not sure what format that means), not just burn the MKV files.

Comment: Yes, a BD Player would have to be capable of playing MKV files otherwise you can use tsMuxerR to convert your Matroska files to BD format.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works and solves my problem. I can say for burning multiple video files though, it is very inconvenient, as it does not create chapters for each file, and it does not create a menu. If I burn a 12 episode season, I now have to fast forward through the first 11 episodes to get to the 12th.

Comment: Have you tried inserting chapter points as in this [guide](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/convert_mkv_to_avchd_for_ps3_and_blu-ray.cfm) ?

Answer (score 3):

The freeware [multiAVCHD](http://multiavchd.deanbg.com/) seems like what you are asking for
(although I have no experience with it).

It supports multiple video files in various formats including MKV,
and can build a menu.